# (JAVA) Recursive String method to Traverse a Binary Tree and add a character for each iteration?

Tags: java, recursion, search, tree, binary

I'm trying to design a method that searches for a character Node and returns its "address" when it is found. If the Node has to go to its left pointer on its way, I add a "0" to the string; If the Node has to turn to its right pointer, I add a "1" to the String. Take the following Tree for example for a visual representation:

[image]

If I want to use the method to search for Node B, for example, the String returned would be "0" because it required just 1 left iteration to get B. If I wanted to use the method to search for Node H, the String returned would be "110", because I had to first go through 2 right pointers (the two 1's), and then one left pointer (the final 0) to arrive at that Node.

The edge case String result of me searching for a Node doesn't exist isn't important, since I do not ever plan to use the method to search for the Nodes' characters not present. The edge case of me searching for the root Node isn't important because I will never implement this method to do that either. How can I recursively traverse the Binary Tree and build a String that eventually represents the path it took?

```java
private String address(Node root, String building, char target){
 
   //building represents the String in progress that will eventually be returned when the correct Node is found.

   //target represents the target Node's character that we would look for in the Tree

   //root has left and right pointers to access children.

   //Node.getChar() can be used to access the Node's char and compare it to see if it matches target
 
}
```

Comment: [Guidance on Homework Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/238704). Note this guideline: *Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on the solution to this problem.

We can write a method that will take three parameters as shown below. This method will look up the character passed in the BST in a recursive manner and appends 0 or 1 based on the path it traverses. We cannot use String to pass the path because in Java string is immutable and it will create a new string every time you append a new string. So instead of that you need to use a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`

```
public Node<Character> lookUpRecursivelyChar(Node<Character> node, Character key, StringBuilder path){

        if(node == null || node.value == key){
            return node;
        }

        if(key > node.value){
            return lookUpRecursivelyChar(node.right, key, path.append(1));
        } else {
            return lookUpRecursivelyChar(node.left, key, path.append(0));
        }
    }
```

Data set up and main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Node<Character> charRoot = new Node<>('F');
        BinarySearchTree bstChar = new BinarySearchTree();
        bst.insertChar(charRoot,'B');
        bst.insertChar(charRoot,'G');
        bst.insertChar(charRoot,'A');
        bst.insertChar(charRoot,'D');
        bst.insertChar(charRoot,'I');
        bst.insertChar(charRoot,'C');
        bst.insertChar(charRoot,'E');
        bst.insertChar(charRoot,'H');

        StringBuilder pathChar = new StringBuilder();
        Node<Character> resultForRecursionChar = bstChar.lookUpRecursivelyChar(charRoot,'C',pathChar);
        System.out.println("Found using recursion:" + resultForRecursionChar.value+ " With path "+pathChar.toString());
}
```

Output :

```
Found using recursion: C With path 010
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for

Note: *I have skipped other utility methods that I have written to create BST. To keep the solution concise*.